# SCALA Lift - AJAX form multiple values

Tags: ajax, scala, lift

I have the following form:

```
<form class="lift:form.ajax">
    <input type="hidden" class="lift:StreamIn" id="path" value="PATH" />
    <input type="submit" value="" />
</form>
```

Which feeds into:

```
object StreamIn {

    def render = SHtml.onSubmit(path => {

        StreamServer ! path

    })

}

case class StreamItem(user: String, path: String, level: String, room: String)

object StreamServer extends LiftActor with ListenerManager {

    private var streams: List[StreamItem] = Nil

    def createUpdate = streams

    override def lowPriority = {

        case stream: String if stream.length > 0 =>

            streams :+= StreamItem("James", stream, "_1", "demo-room");
            updateListeners()

    }

}
```

What I'm looking for is a way of passing multiple values to the StreamServer with more than one input.

So instead of the static string values "James", "_1" and "demo-room" they will be passed from the form.

Thanks in advance for any help, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it ok to have several input fields on your ajax form?
If so, how about:

```
<form class="lift:form.ajax">
  <div class="lift:StreamIn">
    <input type="text" name="path" />
    <input type="text" name="user" />
    <input type="text" name="level" />
    <input type="text" name="room" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden" />
  </div>
</form>
```

**Updated:**

```
object StreamIn {
  case class StreamItem(user: String, path: String, level: String, room: String)
  def render = {
    var path= ""
    var user= ""
    var level= ""
    var room= ""
      def process(): JsCmd= {
        val message= StreamItem(user, path, level, room)
        StreamServer ! message
      }

    "name=path" #> SHtml.onSubmit(path= _ ) &
    "name=user" #> SHtml.onSubmit(user= _ ) &
    "name=level" #> SHtml.onSubmit(level= _ ) &
    "name=room" #> SHtml.onSubmit(room= _) &
    "name=hidden" #>  SHtml.hidden(process)

  }
}
```

And change the  lowPriority for:

```
override def lowPriority = {
  case StreamItem(userIn, pathIn, levelIn, roomIn) => {
    streams :+= StreamItem(userIn, pathIn, levelIn, roomIn);
    updateListeners()
  }

}
```

I missed a few } but I hope you get the idea, you may be able to omit some fields like the room and level, if you have them available, you may be able to access them by using a RequestVar.

You can do more reading on ajax forms on the [Simply Lift Book](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-4.8.html#toc-Section-4.8)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the help, definatly on the right track now. I've done the above changes you've mentioned but am getting the following errors when compiling: "Missing paramater type for extended function" this happens for each of the lines: "name=path" #> SHtml.onSubmit(path => path= _ ) etc

Comment: That should be "Missing parameter type for 'expanded' function"

Comment: ok, I updated the  object StreamIn snippet to get rid of that compiler error and edited the html to add a hidden field

Comment: Thanks for the help, why do we need the hidden input? I'm aiming for the form values to be hidden, e.g path, room, level, user and submit the form via a submit button.

Comment: if you are suing regular forms, then there is no need for the extra hidden field, if you are using ajax forms, jQuery does not send the submit button to the lift server, so for the form to actually work you need a hidden field.